# How to reset a postgresql cursor with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

This code is reading data in chunks between certain dates.
The problem is - once I stop the script, for instance with ctrl-c, and then restart, the cursor position continues at the same position / datetime where it stopped.
How could it be done so that every time the script will be started the query begins at the beginning of the date range. In this case 2023-03-01? At the moment I need to restart the postgres server to achieve the reset, which is obviously a bad solution

```
import psycopg2 
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date
import time
import sys
import os

for i in range(3,7):
    try:
        
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
                    host="localhost",
                    database="dbx",
                    port=5432,
                    user="whatever",
                    options="-c search_path=dbo,data",
                    password="xxxx")
        #cur = conn.cursor()
        cur = conn.cursor(name=f'cursor_{i}')
        start_date = date(2023, i, 1)
        end_date = date(2023, i+1, 1) if i < 12 else date(2024, 1, 1)
        
        chunk_size = 100
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data.table WHERE datetime >= %s AND datetime <= %s", (start_date, end_date))

        rows = cur.fetchmany(chunk_size)

      
        while rows:
            for row in rows:
                time.sleep(0.004)
                rmq_tx= {"...some db stuff here..."}

                print(rmq_tx)

            rows = cur.fetchmany(chunk_size)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        cur.close()
        conn.rollback()
        conn.commit() 
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
    finally:
        cur.close()
        conn.rollback()
        conn.commit() 
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: 1) This `conn.rollback()   conn.commit()` is sending a mixed  message.  Once you rollback a commit is not going to do anything. 2) Where and how are you using this code?

Comment: It doesn't work eitherway

Comment: You have not answered 2) from my comment.

Comment: At the moment I'm using it on my local machine (macOS) and I'm using it with rabbitMQ, but this psycopg2 part is exactly as you see it here. I intend to use the db query on an ubuntu server in the future. The db table contains millions of rows, so it is iterating through, that's why I'm interrupting very often

Comment: Yes, but you are running the code somehow/somewhere. Is that in the Python REPL, IPython, a GUI client, from a script, etc?

Comment: I run it in VS Code or from the terminal (simply executing the .py script)

Comment: 1) Run it in the Python REPL or IPython or from a script and see what happens. 2) Either use rollback or commit. 3) Move `conn.close()` into the `finally` clause.

Comment: Usually i start it like this: python3 script.py. This is REPL mode (optional with -i flag) , isn't it? I tried it with rollback or commit and  moved conn.close() into the finally clause, but no change

Comment: 1) Crank up the logging to `log_statement= 'all'` in Postgres via [postgresql.conf What](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT) and look at what is actually hitting the database. Remember to reset `log_statement` as `all` will generate a lot of logs. 2) Create a simple test script to verify `except KeyboardInterrupt` is actually doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has no ORDER BY, so the database can return the rows in any order it pleases.  In this case, its pleasure is to start up again roughly where the last one left off. The 'missing' rows will be returned at the end, if you read that far.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but a simple test case that works for me:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import psycopg2


try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(database='farm_db', user='farm_admin', host='localhost')
    cur = con.cursor('test_cur')
    eqpt_qry = "select * from eqpt_model_info"
    cur.execute(eqpt_qry)
    for row in cur:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        print(row)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    cur.close()
    con.commit() 
    try:
        sys.exit(0)
    except SystemExit:
        os._exit(0)
finally:
    cur.close()
    con.commit() 
    con.close()
```

Running it once:

```
aklaver@ranger:~/software_projects> python3 close_cur.py 
(1, 'trc', 'A-B Bolinder-Munktell', 'Volvo', 'T425', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
(2, 'trc', 'A-B Bolinder-Munktell', 'Volvo', 'T55', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
(3, 'trc', 'A.D. Baker Co.', 'Baker', '43-67', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
(4, 'trc', 'AGCO', 'AGCO', 'DT160', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
(5, 'trc', 'AGCO', 'AGCO', 'DT180', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
(6, 'trc', 'AGCO', 'AGCO', 'LT75', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
...
^C
```

Running it second time:

```
aklaver@ranger:~/software_projects> python3 close_cur.py 
(1, 'trc', 'A-B Bolinder-Munktell', 'Volvo', 'T425', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
(2, 'trc', 'A-B Bolinder-Munktell', 'Volvo', 'T55', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
(3, 'trc', 'A.D. Baker Co.', 'Baker', '43-67', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
(4, 'trc', 'AGCO', 'AGCO', 'DT160', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
(5, 'trc', 'AGCO', 'AGCO', 'DT180', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
(6, 'trc', 'AGCO', 'AGCO', 'LT75', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
(7, 'trc', 'AGCO', 'AGCO', 'LT75A', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
(8, 'trc', 'AGCO', 'AGCO', 'LT90', None, datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 16, 11, 2, 50, 789198, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200))), None, 'farm_admin', None)
...
^C
```

Comment: I used your code only with my credentials but the problem persists.

Comment: I'm not sure where to go from here as it works for me. I would still recommend looking at the Postgres log to make sure what you think is happening actually is.